# Вывести значение из списка словарей

Tags: python, list, словари

Есть список со словарями

```
[{"ID":"100059","STATUS_ID":"F","status":"completed","shop_ID":"1021440"},
{"ID":"100060","STATUS_ID":"F","status":"completed","shop_ID":"1021576"},
{"ID":"100061","STATUS_ID":"F","status":"canceled","shop_ID":"1021841"}]
```

Как мне вывести значение "status" для shop_ID":"1021841"?

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно быстрое решение (в плане скорости написания), то можно обычным перебором пройтись и проверить значение

```py
data = [{"ID": "100059", "STATUS_ID": "F", "status": "completed", "shop_ID": "1021440"},
        {"ID": "100060", "STATUS_ID": "F", "status": "completed", "shop_ID": "1021576"},
        {"ID": "100061", "STATUS_ID": "F", "status": "canceled", "shop_ID": "1021841"}]

for item in data:
    if item["shop_ID"] == "1021841":
        print(item["status"])
```

Вывод будет

```
canceled
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Phyton\ozontest\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    if item['ID'] == "99622":
TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @ДмитрийАксёнов какая версия питона и как запускаешь проект?

Answer (score 0):

Если спсок не длинный то можно и перебором (или нужно на один раз)
Но если список горазд длинее чем 3 элемента а данных за сессию из него нужно много и разных, то лучше так

```py
a = [{"ID":"100059","STATUS_ID":"F","status":"completed","shop_ID":"1021440"},
{"ID":"100060","STATUS_ID":"F","status":"completed","shop_ID":"1021576"},
{"ID":"100061","STATUS_ID":"F","status":"canceled","shop_ID":"1021841"}]

d = {item.pop('ID'): item for item in a}
print(
    d['100060'].get('status')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать функцию [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```py
li = [{"ID":"100059","STATUS_ID":"F","status":"completed","shop_ID":"1021440"},
{"ID":"100060","STATUS_ID":"F","status":"completed","shop_ID":"1021576"},
{"ID":"100061","STATUS_ID":"F","status":"canceled","shop_ID":"1021841"}]

filtered = filter(lambda x: x['shop_ID'] == '1021841', li)
statuses = [x['status'] for x in filtered]
print(*statuses)
```

```py
canceled
```